# Java UnsupportedClassVersionError 8240.8224

Tags: java, jar

I get this error code while trying to open a `.class` of a JAR.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: <class file>:
        Unsupported major.minor version 8240.8224
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `@Java Learner` **Welcome to StackOverflow!** Please, try to format your posts correctly; separate each paragraph with a **blank line**, etc. See [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here are known valid `major`.`minor` versions of Java `.class` files:

```
major  minor Java platform version 
45       3           1.0
45       3           1.1
46       0           1.2
47       0           1.3
48       0           1.4
49       0           1.5
50       0           1.6
51       0           1.7
```

The `8240.8224` is *way* too big, I suppose your `.class` file is corrupted. have you tried decompiling it? Or simply run:

```
$ od -N4 -j4 -t d1 Foo.class
```

It should print something like this:

```
0000004    0    0    0   49  //49.0 - Java 5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

8224 is the 16-bit value of two space bytes, 0x2020. It isn't a .class file. Maybe a .java file in disguise?